# Android background service that will record keyboard events

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, keyboard, motionevent

I would like to know how to create an app that will run a background service recording MotionEvents at a specific time and store them in some sort of list. Then, when requested, would replay these MotionEvents in order to simulate the user interacting with the device.

Comment: What have you tried sofar ?

Comment: First of all, such a service is a huge security/privacy issue, so normally it can't be really done without a root permission. That being said, there is some hack that makes it possible: [accessibility service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#register). Accessibility service wasn't really designed for such use cases, so we can expect Google will one day forbid it, but for now there are apps for recording touch macros in the Play Store. Also note that users need to get through additional steps to give an application such great powers.